# A man invited five friends.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday

A man invited five friends. He was born in April as also all the invited friends. What is the probability that none of the friends was born on the same day of the month as the host?

The way I approached it was $\frac{(30\times 29^5)}{(30^6)}$. However, there is yet another equally convincing way i.e. Probability that a friend's birthday is on the same day as the host is $\frac{1}{30}$. So if this goes for all friends then we have $\big(\frac{1}{30}\big)^5$. And we want the negation of it so $1-\big(\frac{1}{30}\big)^5$.

Which one is correct?

Comment: $\left(\frac 1{30}\right)^5$ computes the probability that *all* of the friends share the hosts birthday.  That's not the complementary event to the one you care about.

Comment: so was my initial approach wrong and if yes how so?

Comment: Yes, your first approach is fine.  The probability that a given friend has a birthday different from the hosts is $\frac {29}{30}$ so the probability that none of the friends have the same birthday as the host is $\left(\frac {29}{30}\right)^5$.

Comment: But the answer differs

Comment: Which answers differ?

Comment: (29/30)^5 = 0.844... and 1-(1/30)^5=0.99999...

Comment: As I said, the second method is wrong...so why would you expect it to get the same answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131425/discussion-between-waqar-ahmed-and-lulu).

Comment: I think we've said what we need to.  The second method is wrong. It computes the probability that at least one friend has a different birthday from the host.  That's not what you were asked to find.

Comment: @Lulu is right. I also did it by simulation in R. Code `set.seed(1113);
host = sample(1:30, 1);  match.host = replicate(10^6, sum(host==sample(1:30, 5, rep=T)));  mean(match.host==0)` returns $0.844427,$ which matches Lulu's answer $(29/30)^5=0.8440802$ within the expected 2 to 3 places of accuracy for a simulation with a million iterations.

Comment: @lulu you should put that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comments...

There are a total of $30$ days, where each day is independent of the other. The probability that the host is born on the $n_{th}$ day is $Pr(X = n) = \frac{1}{30}$, if the host is equally likely to be born on any day of this month. The probability that each friend is born on the $n_{th}$ day is also $\frac{1}{30}$ and similarly **not** on the $n_{th}$ day, is $\frac{29}{30}$. So it would be $(\frac{29}{30})^5$. As for $1 - (\frac{1}{30})^5$, this just means your including **everything** else except the all of the his friends being born on the same day. Note that set **does not just** include the events: all the friends being born on the same day or none of them being born on the same day.

Alternatively, the set is **binomially** distributed. What if $4$ friends are born on the same day and $1$ is not **or** $2$ friends are born on the same day and $3$ are not?

In mathematical notation **your stating** that, $$Pr(X = \text{None of his friends}) = 1 - Pr(X = \text{All of his friends})$$ $$Pr(X = 0) = 1 - Pr(X = 5)$$ This is incorrect as $$Pr(X = 5) = 1 - Pr(X \leq 4), \text{and }$$ $$Pr(X = 0) = 1 - Pr(X \ge 1), \text{and }X\sim Bi(n, p)$$